# Determining chemical state and oxidation state from XPS analysis

Tags: spectroscopy

This is an call for help! I have performed XPS analysis of my samples to get chemical state in which each element is present. I had given the samples to a third party lab. The operator has provided me with an excel sheet and I am attaching a picture of the peak tablehere. I have no prior experience in analysing XPS data and am having a hard time in deciphering the chemical state of each element.

[image]

The operator has given me the fitted data for each element and binding energy range for each element. I was under the assumption that I just need to compare the peak binding energy of each element to the reference databases available. But for my peak binding energy/energies there is not reference chemical state for that element.

For eg. For Pt 4F5/2 orbital, peak BE is 74.76 but there is no reference chemical state for this Pt with this orbital. I tried searching in open sources databases and in literature. In this case, according to papers there can be a shift depending on the chemical environment surronding the atoms but how to decipher this information i.e what shift is happening and due to what?

Any help or any link to any good literature which illustrates the process of finding chemical state of elements from fitted data will be highly appreciated.

Comment: XPS manufacturers also have reference tables for each element. I recall that very well. Please ask the operator to provide the name of reference handbook and then visit a good library. He/she must be using them regularly. Don't waste your time on web searching and open databases. Not everything is free. There are thick reference books that tabulate these but their name escapes now.